# Python dictionary not adding new keys

Tags: dictionary

I have checked a few of the posts having the same issue and it tells me how to do it but it is not working.

My code:

```
class Product:
    def __init__(self,price,prod_id,quantity):
        self.price = price
        self.prod_id = prod_id
        self.quantity = quantity
        self.shop_inventory = {}
        self.amount = {}

class Inventory(Product):
    def update_stock(self):
        self.shop_inventory[self.prod_id] = self.quantity
        self.amount[self.prod_id] = self.price

    def return_stock_item(self):
        look_up = input("What item would you like to check? ")
        item = self.shop_inventory[look_up.lower()]
        price = self.amount[look_up.lower()]

        return f"{look_up.capitalize()}: There are {item} in stock and cost ${price} each."

    def display_stock(self):
        return self.amount.items()
```

To set the values Ive been using

```
stock = Inventory(2.34,'apple',5)

stock.update_stock()
```

It's part of a class and everything else in the class is working right. Just this one function is not working. I have tried this method as well as the update() method and neither are adding new key values. It is only over writing the same first spot. I have an item check in the class for all the dictionary items and it always only returns one [key][value] no matter how many times I change the key name.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: What "new key" is failing to be added?  There's only one key shown in the code fragment you posted.

Comment: I am passing keys into the self.prod_id from the __init__(). Say I was using fruit. I add 'apple' into self.prod_id and 5 into self.quantity. Apple is the key. Then I send in another key as 'orange'. It will over write apple and display orange when I ask for the self.shop_inventory.items(). From what I was understanding from the course and from what I have found and read, if they "key" does not exist then it will be added to the dictionary. I feel like im missing something

Comment: What you're missing is *code that actually exhibits the problem*.  It sounds like you're creating multiple instances of this class, each of which has its own separate inventory.

Comment: My course had me create a product class to input stuff about the product and then an inventory class to manage all the products. I inherited the product class into the inventory class to input the product and manage it from the inventory class. I'll update my post to show my code and what code I am running to set it up. Maybe I'm overthinking things

Comment: This is just broken.  First of all, `Inventory` should not be a subclass of `Product` - unless you somehow believe that Inventory is a *kind of* Product.  `Product` should have only the details that pertain to a specific item (id and price), `Inventory` should have only a collection of `Product`s.  In other words, you'd create a single `Inventory`, and then add one or more `Product`s to it.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I'll rework my code. I'm still trying to get the hang of classes and how they work. Only been at python for like a month or so.